# Is there a Stack Exchange site for military related topics?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a few questions about military hardware, military regulations, and military policies. Is there a site where I can ask such questions?

Comment: As the closure/redirect here implies, the short answer is no. But _depending on the individual questions_ you wanted to ask, you might be able to get some answers at [History SE](http://history.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Chris while mentioning the "How to propose a site" in a comment is good idea, I don't think we should close any site recommendation question with "no, there is no such site" as duplicate of it. If for example next month there will be such a site or proposal, then we can post answer here. No need to close it first.

Comment: @Rich now that you  proposed such a site on Area 51 please post a self answer mentioning it, this way those interested can see it and follow the proposal.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks! 'Tis done.

Comment: I may be a masochist: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354393/343170

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have proposed a site on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) for discussing [military topics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/99463/militaria).

Militaria is a place to ask about topics for any military.

- Military culture.
- Life in the military.
- Military regulations.
- Use of military by nations to effect policies.
- Military technologies.
- Veterans of the military.
- Families with members in the military.
- Military history.
- Compare militaries of different nations.

Please join the proposed site and post your own example questions to help it through the definition phase.

Comment: That proposal has since been deleted.

Comment: I really don't get why these proposals get deleted. I assume a lot of people would have questions regarding this, I myself am now at a loss regarding where to ask my question...

Answer (score 2):

Retrying a similar proposal:

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/116078/military

Comment: That proposal has since been deleted, so this answer is no longer relevant.