# Would a Stack Exchange site devoted to military-related matters be off-topic?

Tags: support, area-51

On Area 51, there were at least [two proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279769/343170). Both were deleted.

> Proposals with insufficient activity are subject to removal. Occasionally, proposals may also be removed for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etc.

If I may ask, were these removals due to "insufficient activity" or due to military-related matters being considered off-topic?

The reason I ask this question is that I see no point in gathering a few people and attempting to start a new SE site that will never take off due to its being considered off-topic.

---

- [Is there interest in a military SE?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28148/169329)
- [Are there any banned subjects on Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350157/343170)

Comment: Purely for the military, I think not.  But [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) has a [military tag](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military), have you seen it?

Comment: Those proposals were probably closed due to a lacking community. You first need to find and organize your experts, then start the proposal and have all your experts commit. Sites are not started out of thin air and SE will not do the leg work that is needed to engage with the experts you need.

Comment: @rene "Probably" is not good enough. I would like to be sure.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Only those who closed the proposal can say for sure.

Comment: @Ollie I suppose that defense policy would be on-topic at Politics SE, but actual warfare not so much.

Comment: The link at the end of your question seems to point to the wrong Area51 question.

Comment: @wimi What do you mean?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo at the end of this question, there is a link that says "Is there interest in a military SE?". But that link points to a question about "a separate community for Ionic".

Comment: @wimi My goal was to emphasize that there have been proposals to create a Military SE. If a question has been closed is not enormously relevant, I would say.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo there seems to be some misunderstanding here. Your question has a link to this question: [Don't we need the seperate community for Ionic?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28107/dont-we-need-the-seperate-community-for-ionic), which has nothing to do with military. It is about an app development framework.

Comment: @wimi My question links to question #28148. When you click on it, do you get redirected to question #28107?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes. I see, this is really weird...

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ok, I see what happened, it is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr). I was automatically redirected from an unanswered duplicate question to its duplicate target. Why those two Area51 questions are duplicates of each other, I have no idea... It might be that other users with no account on Area51 get redirected in the same way as me.

Comment: It could be a good proposal. There is a fine difference between military tag of [politics.se] and what a general military.se would be. I can guess dozens of military topics which are off-topic for politics as well as history.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are very few subjects that are considered "off-topic" on Area 51. This is not one of them. Both previous proposals mentioned were automatically closed and deleted by the system, one due to lack of activity and one due to a year having passed without making it to the commitment phase (back when the time allotments were longer - that is now reduced to four months).

If you have an interested community already established, there is nothing preventing you from pursuing a site for the topic.